Mockito and Spring RestTemplate issue
I want to test this class :
public class TokenIntrospector {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private String userInfoUri = "http://localhost";

    public TokenIntrospector(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public String introspect(String data) {
        var userinfo = findUserInfo(data);
        return userinfo.name();
    }

    private UserInfo findUserInfo(String token) {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
        headers.set("Authorization", format("Bearer %s", token));

        var userinfoRequest = new HttpEntity<UserInfo>(headers);

        var userinfo = restTemplate.exchange(userInfoUri,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                userinfoRequest,
                UserInfo.class);

        return userinfo.getBody();
    }
}

The issue comes from this line :
restTemplate.exchange(userInfoUri,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    userinfoRequest,
                    UserInfo.class);

It is calling this method (in Spring code) :
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(String url, HttpMethod method,
            @Nullable HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)
            throws RestClientException {

        RequestCallback requestCallback = httpEntityCallback(requestEntity, responseType);
        ResponseExtractor<ResponseEntity<T>> responseExtractor = responseEntityExtractor(responseType);
        return nonNull(execute(url, method, requestCallback, responseExtractor, uriVariables));
    }

Here is my test code :
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TokenIntrospectorTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private TokenIntrospector tokenIntrospector;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        when(restTemplate.exchange(
                anyString(),
                any(HttpMethod.class),
                any(HttpEntity.class),
                any(Class.class),
                Optional.ofNullable(any()))
        ).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(new UserInfo(
                "a")));

        String introspect = tokenIntrospector.introspect("data");

    }
}

Here is the error I got :
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'exchange' method:
    restTemplate.exchange(
    "http://localhost",
    GET,
    <[Accept:"application/json", Authorization:"Bearer data"]>,
    class com.example.UserInfo
);
    -> at com.example.TokenIntrospector.findUserInfo(TokenIntrospector.java:35)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. restTemplate.exchange(
    "",
    null,
    null,
    null,
    Optional.empty
);
      -> at com.example.TokenIntrospectorTest.test(TokenIntrospectorTest.java:32)
Typically, stubbing argument mismatch indicates user mistake when writing tests.


The internal call isn't going to happen because it is a mock. SO record and verify behavior of the method you are actually calling not what the RestTemplate is doing internally (as that doesn't exist anymore when you create a mock).

@M.Deinum Not sure to understand what you meant  by "internal call"
I want to test this method : "public String introspect(String data)" from TokenIntrospector . This method depends on restTemplate. So I just want to mock restTemplate to get back fake data.

You are making the assumption that exhange(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) is calling ex change(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5) this isn't the case with a mock only if you would use the real implementation. You are calling the one with 4 arguments that is also the one you need to mock.

@M.Deinum You're absolutely right. I didn't even know there was exhange(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4). when clicking on restTemplate.exchange(userInfoUri,
HttpMethod.GET,
userinfoRequest,
UserInfo.class) my IDE redirects me to exchange(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5). So I mocked this method with 5 arguments

Well it might even call the one with 5 arguments (at least the last one is Object... but then still your initial matchers wouldn't match as you aren't passing an Optional. You are passing nothing.

Optional.ofNullable(any()) does not make sense. If you stub a method call, you can either use direct arguments or only argument matchers. Optinnal.ofNullable(any()) is not a matcher and equivalent to Optional.empty() (but it will pollute Mockito's argument matching stack).
So maybe you wanted to say any(Optional.class) or eq(Optional.empty())?
That said, your code is only passing 4 arguments to the exchange method, so you must stub the call with 4 arguments and not the call with 5 arguments:
when(
    restTemplate.exchange(
        eq("http://localhost),
        eq(HttpMethod.GET),
        any(HttpEntity.class),
        eq(UserInfo.class))
    .thenReturn(…);

